# How to use new line character in Text Widget Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to display multiline text in Flutter?

```
Text("Text1\n Text2\n Text3",maxLines: 20, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0 ,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.black) , )
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

**Approach 1** Using Triple quotes

```
      child: Container(
         child :  Text('''
                          Text1
                          Text2
                          Text3''',maxLines: 20, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0 ,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.black) , )
      ),
```

**Approach 2** Using **\n** here is example with Dynamic String :

```
        var readLines = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'];
        String getNewLineString() {
           StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
           for (String line in readLines) {
              sb.write(line + "\n");
           }
           return sb.toString();
        }


        child: Container(
           child: Text(
          getNewLineString(),
          maxLines: 20,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black),
        )),
```

**Approach 3** using static text with \n

```
  Text('Welcome\nto\nMyWorld\nHello\nWorld\n');
```

For more, you should refer to this link
https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.0/dart-core/String-class.html

Comment: Thanks @Amit Prajapati, Do you know how to achieve the same if the text is taken from a server response. With local text in the above format is working fine.

Comment: Can you post here what response string you have and how you want to show like ?

Comment: You might have to replace space with \n

Comment: I have mentioned the same (\n) in my question .. which is not working

Comment: I check it showing in new line, do you mean while you split with space and added with \n in variable its not work ?

Comment: with new line chars from server is not working but I modified it again locally to put newline char wherever needed , its working now . Thanks.

Comment: Triple quotes is not working. I'm using i18n resource files for my strings. \n works fine.

Answer (score 28):

For me, when getting data with '\n' in the text from the local sqlite database, this worked:

```dart
    var message = await db.getDataFromDB();
    return Text(message.replaceAll('\\n', '\n'))
```

Comment: This worked for data from db, api, remote server.. ;) thx..

Answer (score 5):

If you want to break line with a string that comes from outside the Flutter you should modify the string inside flutter.

So if you get from API a string 'Order received! \n Wait in the line!' and the break line is not working, in flutter you should replace the '\n' inside flutter

```
var response = await getMessageFromServer();
String message = getMessage(response);
return Text(message.replaceAll('\n', '\n'))
```

This way you will see how the color of '\n' is different in flutter.

I prefered using '/n' for the API and then in flutter I replace.all('/n', '\n')

Comment: Your code did not work for me. `.replaceAll(r'\n', '\n')` works.

Comment: replace.all('/n', '\n') worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

One other option I found is to use a `RichText` widget as follows:

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'A line with a newline character\n',
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: 'A second line',
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this

```
Text('${userInfo.name}'
                        '\n${userInfo.email}'
                        '\n${userInfo.mobilenumber}',maxLines: 20, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0 ,fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.black) , )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write multiple lines of text in the `Text()` widget by simply enclose every line of text with a separate quote(" ").
Like this, look at the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting any String from APIs, Firebase, etc having '\n' in it. You can follow the below step:

```
String data = dataFromAPI(); //For eg. it returns "How are you?\nI am good!"
String newData = data.replaceAll('\\n', '\n');
```

Here, if you display the newData anywhere, it will have new lines added. This works for any data you might be receiving from external to flutter.