# Use newline in string by json

Tags: flutter, dart, newline

I have a JSON like this:

```
{
"luid": 1,
"uid": 1,
"description": "Inside there are some buildings:\n- houses,\n- skyscrapers,\n- bridges",
"visible": 1
}
```

When I fetch the json in dart, I put all the fields in separate getters.

In the UI, printing the description field in a `Text`, I see:

```
Inside there are some buildings:\n- houses,\n- skyscrapers,\n- bridges
```

Instead of:

```
Inside there are some buildings:
- houses,
- skyscrapers,
- bridges
```

The code is this:

```
_respserver =
        await cl.get('datacontents.json');
_analyzed = json.decode(utf8.decode(_respserver.bodyBytes));

Text(_analyzed['description'])
```

How can fix?

Comment: you can do it dynamically as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57992926/how-to-use-new-line-character-in-text-widget-flutter hope it helps

Comment: Can you add a code snippet of what you have done ?

Comment: I added code to have the text element

Comment: How are you parsing this JSON? I can't decode it with dart's `jsonDecode` because of the incorrect newline character. Can you change the JSON?

Comment: I added code to parse the json. I can't change that because there are also special characters.

Comment: Can you change the JSON? How are special characters relevant to that? How do you know this is the JSON you currently have?

Comment: I thought it works normally. I just tried this and it's running okay. Maybe your string is getting changed somewhere.

Comment: I agree with @VisakhVijayan. This seems like it should work. Please share what `utf8.decode(_respserver.bodyBytes)` is. The JSON before it's decoded.

Comment: The json gives result from a mysql database. The newline character can be real or not (real \n and \ n in 2 bytes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify your received JSON string to replace all of the `\n` with a real newline character.

Based on your current output you have raw separate `\` and `n` characters next to each other. So to fix this we just need to find all of those instances and replace them with what we want.

We first have to search for instances of `\\\\n`, which may seem complicated, but once you consider the escape characters, it turns into a raw `\\n`, which is what's really currently in your json. When the json decoder sees this, it doesn't see a newline character since you escape it with the backslash at the beginning, leading to a literal `\n` in the output.

Once we find the undesirable instances, we need to replace it with what we really want, `\\n`. This turns into a raw `\n` as explained before. The json decoder then see this as a newline character and creates it as such in the decoded output leading to your desired result when you show it in the `Text` widget.

```dart
_respserver = await cl.get('datacontents.json');
String jsonRaw = utf8.decode(_respserver.bodyBytes);
jsonRaw = jsonRaw.replaceAll("\\\\n","\\n");//Find and replace undesirable instances here
_analyzed = json.decode(jsonRaw);

Text(_analyzed['description'])
```

---

To do it after decoding, do the following:

```dart
_respserver = await cl.get('datacontents.json');
_analyzed = json.decode(utf8.decode(_respserver.bodyBytes));

_analyzed['description'] = _analyzed['description'].replaceAll("\\n" ,"\n");

Text(_analyzed['description'])
```

Comment: Is it possible to do first json.decode and after the \n replacement?

Comment: @dam034 Yes. Why would you want to do that? I edited in how to do it.

Comment: I parse json in a ChangeNotifier and give the contents to a Consumer, in the Consumer I can put replacements only for fields where I need it

Comment: @dam034 I still don't see the problem, but whatever works for you. Did you see my edit? Does that help?

Comment: Was searching for a solution to a similar problem with data I get from an API and while I had the same idea (just replace \\n with \n), it quickly breaks if you consider the fact that data can also contain other symbols that were treated the same way (like the ' became `u34243` - something like that, you get the idea. So you'll need to parse text for each such symbol? There has to be a better solution to this. Doing .replaceAll is a quick hack, need smth more reliable.

Comment: @galloper How would it be possible for the data to "contain other symbols that were treated the same way". Please provide a better example.

Comment: Well, you see how it treated new lines? in my case I was getting not only that in the original json, but also special symbols that were encoded as 'uXXXX' (X=number) and obviously getting into the string data as is (same way as OP had \n in it). My final solution to this was to change the API itself to encoding text data as base64 (because basically it was not only Latin-script data), then decoding in Flutter client.. however, had I not have access to the API, what would I do?

Comment: @galloper That's a separate issue, unrelated to the OP's. It does not detract from the validity of this solution. That is only the case when you have special data, in which case doing JSON encoding was not a good idea in the first place.